# Migrating to NSURLSession from NSURLConnection incompatible pointer types

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I'm moving from `NSURLConnection` to `NSURLSession` and running into a problem with the `NSMutableURLRequest` that holds values for the URL request.

Any ideas on how to retain this info in the `NSURLSession` without getting this error:

> incompatible pointer types sending nsmutableurlrequest to parameter of
>   type nesting * _nonull nsurl urlwithstring

I see that this line `[NSURL URLWithString:myRequest]` wants a NSString, but how to I still pass the other info that is on my `NSMutableURLRequest`?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: myURL];
[acquisitionRequest setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myRequest]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {                
            }] resume];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` instead of `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:`. This way you can pass the whole request in. If it complains about being mutable, you can copy it to get rid of the mutable state.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: myURL]; 
[acquisitionRequest setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

[[session dataTaskWithRequest:[myRequest copy]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                // completion stuff
}] resume];
```

Comment: Thanks BIG TIME Keith. It seems like a happy camper without the copy but I will test and will approve it after testing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are passing `NSMutableURLRequest` object while creating URL using `URLWithString:` which is expecting you to pass `NSString`. Pass `myURL` instead of `[NSURL URLWithString:myRequest]` and you should be good.

However, I would also advise to use `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am receiving the similar issue.  I can't login on iOS 9 because NSData has been deprecated.  I need to update to NSURLSession.   I am attempting to do so with the code below, but - It appears there are two lines still drawing from NSData, where as my pointer to them is an NSURLSession.

It is aggravating the system.  How do I set the receiving lines open to connect with NSURLSession  ?

```
    NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSLog(@"response%@",response);
    NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

    if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
    {
        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:session encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

        NSError *error = nil;
      /* NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                  JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error:&error];*/
       // NSLog(@"dict%@",jsonData);
        self.topLevelArray3 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:session options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        for (int i=0; i<[self.topLevelArray3 count]; i++) {
```